# Use of dpkg --print-architecture to control build in a makefile

Tags: debian, make, gnu

I am trying to figure out some work around to use `dpkg --print-architecture` in a Makefile. No responses to my previous query on gnustep, so I'll try again with my last failed work around. From everything that I have read, I would be led to believe that the following should work. But it doesn't, and I suspect there is something really basic I am missing. It appears that `TARGETS` is never set. There are some messages to that effect, and they do not match up with what I believed was going on but was obviously mistaken about. Has anyone played with this?

```
CPU=`dpkg --print-architecture`

amd64_TARGETS = one two
arm64_TARGETS = two
armhf_TARGETS = one

define SET_TARGETS =
 TARGETS   = $$($(1)_TARGETS)
endef

$(eval $(call SET_TARGETS,$(CPU)))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)
        echo all $(TARGETS)

one:
        echo do one

two:
        echo do two
```

Answer (score 3):

In a `Makefile`,

```
CPU=`dpkg --print-architecture`
```

sets the `CPU` variable to the literal string `` `dpkg --print-architecture` ``, backticks included. To run `dpkg --print-architecture` and set `CPU` to whatever is output, you need

```
CPU=$(shell dpkg --print-architecture)
```

instead.

Your `Makefile` will then work as expected.

The construction of `TARGETS` can be simplified:

```make
amd64_TARGETS = one two
arm64_TARGETS = two
armhf_TARGETS = one

TARGETS = $($(CPU)_TARGETS)
```

Comment: Thanks for applying a spare set of eyeballs. I could have stared at that for days and not seen/realized the problem with the backticks, that their execution was delayed. Everything else was an attempt to deal with that core problem.